# Doesn't C11 _Generic contradict the 'essence' of the C preprocessor?

Tags: c, generics, c11

I remember being constantly told that the C preprocessor does not know C. It doesn't know about types, doesn't remember declared symbols, etc. If that's the case, how can it possibly act differently based on the type of its parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `_Generic` feature is not processed by the preprocessor. It is a *primary expression* that is treated with higher preference than most other expressions.

Comment: So, the preprocessor ignores it, essentially?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing special about `_Generic` for the preprocessor.

Comment: @einpoklum examples of `_Generic` always occur inside macros because there is no use for the feature anywhere else (you could just type out the case you want instead of typing out the whole `_Generic` structure); but as it always was, the macro is a simple text replacement.